# Using an iPad to view video from a set top box / DVD player over HDMI?

Tags: ios, ipad, video, hdmi

From time to time I need to test set top boxes / DVD players, currently I carry around a 20" HDMI monitor to test them on, but is it possible to use an iPad as an display with an HDMI input adaptor (perhaps also requiring an app to view the video feed). So the setup would be:

`Set top box --hdmi--> adaptor ----> ipad`

Answer (score 1):

It can be expensive. iPads are really designed to only [output video](http://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/product/MD098AM/A/is-it-possible-to-go-the-other-way-also/QYYD4C9J972J492YP), but if you have a thousand bucks you want to spend [on this device](http://teradek.com/pages/cube), it should work.